# Google Rich Snippet not working

Tags: wordpress, rich-snippets

I am unable to activate Google rich snippet with my website www.hensdry.net As it shows all good in Google Structured tool but in Google results it does not show the results it suppose to be.
My website is [www.hensdry.net](http://www.hensdry.net/)
Thanks
Jim

Comment: Further to songdogtech's answer - it can take up to 6 weeks for Google to honour your authorship information when returning your content in search results

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a G+ image next to SERPs and Google's validator at http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets ?

Having correct structured data is only the first step in getting your G+ image next to SERPs. The final decision is up to Google, and they have recently reduced the number of sites that get the benefit of structured data. See http://www.google.com/search?q=google+reduces+authorship

Comment: Thanks for your kind response.According to above links it says 15% to 20% rich snippet has been removed by Google.Low quality websites not suppose to have Google Rich Snippet but only good quality websites.Now I am afraid with what parameters Google suppose to analysis a website ? what needs to be done for make it good quality website?

Answer (score 0):

Google take some time to crawl your pages & detect the structured codes added to your page's code. Adding structured code doesn't guarantee rich snippets. It all depends on the search query from the users. If the search query matches the data in your structured code, Google would show it a rich snippet. Otherwise, the regular snippet that matches the search query will be shown.

Reference: [rich snippet](https://www.learnly.info/rich-snippet-what-is-it-how-do-you-get-it/) guide by [learnly.info](https://www.learnly.info/)